# Register protocol "https" multi-threading with certificate for request in SOAP(Axis 2)

Tags: java, multithreading, soap, https, apache-axis

I have created a service to register the "https" protocol and inject the certificate into it using SocketFactory implementation, only one request at a time works normally, but using multi-threading is like registering only once and webservice SOAP takes as was the wrong certificate.
Webservice SOAP classes were generated by Axis 2 using the WSDL saved from the page.

**Code to register the protocol with certificate:**

```
public boolean sign(InputStream pfx, final String password) throws Exception {
    try {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(getBytesFromInputStream(pfx));
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        ks.load(in, password.toCharArray());
        in.close();
        Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
        String alias = null;

        while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
            alias = (String) aliases.nextElement();
            if (ks.isKeyEntry(alias)) break;
        }

        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
        SocketFactoryDynamic socketFactoryDinamico = new SocketFactoryDynamic(certificate, privateKey);
        socketFactoryDinamico.setFileCacerts("NFeCacerts");
        Protocol.registerProtocol("https", new Protocol("https", socketFactoryDinamico, 443));
        return true;
    } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | KeyStoreException | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I want to query multiple clients at the same time in webservice, but the certificates are different.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to add a synchronized block around setting the Protocol.registerProtocol and the actual Axis2 call.

```
    synchronized (this) {
    Protocol.registerProtocol("https", getHttpsProtocol());
    SOAPEnvelope response = call.invoke(request, operationName, messageContext);
    return response;
}
```

This way when one thread has set the protocol no other thread can access and set it until the Axis2 call is complete and returns a response

Hope this helps